# Does IronPython support APIs to receive/send data from peripherals?

Tags: api, ironpython

I will receive a hardware which will have native Python API to communicate it through USB. So the device will send image data to Python. It is because they only support with Python API.

I'm stuck because I need to use C# since it is part of the developed application. So I was thinking to embed that hardware USB data commutation using .NET. But I'm vey shocked when I heard they only have Python API. Then I came around IronPython. But I am not sure in my case it would work since I'm talking about a third party API from a small company.

Can I embed this in C# application and communicate through it? So in my case the Python engine should receive data from USB port and transfer it to C# or send data to USB device from C# to Python and then to the device. Is is possible? If not any alternative exits?